# Forking a repository using the Azure az repos CLI

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli

Azure provides an [`az repos` CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos?view=azure-cli-latest) for Azure DevOps that allows convenient programmatic management of repositories.

However, it seems that there is no obvious way to [fork a repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/forks?view=azure-devops&tabs=command-line#create-the-fork) using the `az repos` CLI.

The intended usage pattern here is to fork a target repository from a given project, to a repository in a (possibly) different project within the same Azure DevOps subscription.

A solution that can be executed from a DevOps Pipeline would also be a usable solution here.

Has anyone managed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Rest API to create a fork. you need to use the [Repositories - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/Repositories/Create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Api, and in the URL & Body add the source repository:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?sourceRef={sourceRef}&api-version=6.0
```

For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories?sourceRef=users/heads/master&api-version=6.0
```

Body:

```
{
  "name": "forkRepositoryWithOnlySourceRef",
  "project": {
    "id": "3b046b6a-d070-4cd5-ad59-2eace5d05b90"
  },
  "parentRepository": {
    "id": "76b510af-7910-4a96-9902-b978d6226bee"
  }
}
```